# For a given plane and vectors, and vectors answer yes or no to the following questions

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-geometry

Given the plane is $2x+y-2z=-2$
and the vectors $u=\frac{1}{3}(2,-2,1)$ and  $v=\frac{1}{3}(1,2,2)$, answer the following questions.

1. Find $u \times v$
2. Are $u$ and $v$ orthogonal?
3. Is $u$ a unit vector?
4. Is $v$ a unit vector?
5. Is $u$ parallel to the plane?
6. Is $v$ parallel to the plane?

Comment: why is fraction not showing properly?

Comment: I tried to get that fraction look properly but failed all edits sorry

Comment: I edited your question. Is everything OK now?

Comment: @RobertZ thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that the vector $w=(2,1,-2)$ is orthogonal to the plane $2x+y-2z=-2$. Therefore a vector is parallel to the plane iff it is orthogonal to $w$.

Comment: @Joseph YoSeob Kim What are your answers? Any further doubt?